# How do you change lines of java code through gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am using java. Each time I run the code I want it to change a line of code so it refers to another class. I am wondering if that is possible through gradle.

```
public class test{
    Drive x = new Drive();
}
```

When I set a variable in the gradle file I want gradle to change the **Drive** to **ReverseDrive**

**When build.gradle is run is it possible to change a line of code?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by adding a concrete example?

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY problem. If you describe what you're selecting, we can probably recommend a way to do it. (Note that, in general, you don't run Gradle every time you run your program.)

Comment: I agree this is likely an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you'd add a "generate" task to `build.gradle` which generates a `.java` file(s) in a folder under `$buildDir` (so it's deleted via `gradle clean`). You'd need to wire the task into Gradle's [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) using `Task.dependsOn(...)`. The best solution I've found for this is replacing tokens in template files in `src/template/java`

Eg:

`src/template/java/foo/bar`

```
package foo.bar;
public class MyClass {
     public static String getGeneratedValue() {
          return "${generatedValue}";
     }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
task generateJava(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/template/java'
    into "$buildDir/generated/java"
    expand ['generatedValue': '** generated value goes here **']
}
sourceSets.main.java {
    // add the generated dir to the main source set
    srcDir "$buildDir/generated/java"
}
compileJava.dependsOn generateJava // wire the task into the dag
```

See [Copy.expand(Map)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand(java.util.Map))

Also see [Java Plugin tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks)

[image: Java Plugin Tasks]